# Storing the value of one object in to the other

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying the following code:-

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer[]> possibleSeq = new HashMap<Integer,Integer[] >();
        possibleSeq.put(0,new Integer[]{1,4,5});
        possibleSeq.put(1,new Integer[]{0,4,5,2,6});
        Integer[] store = possibleSeq.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<store.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(store[i] + ' ');
        }
```

Output is :-

```
333637
```

But since i am equating the value when key is 0 to the **store** variable,I intend to get `1 4 5` as an output.So i deduced `Integer[] store = possibleSeq.get(0);`this is not the proper way to store elements of `possibleSeq.get(0)` in **store**.So how should i do it??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding char `' '`(which is converted to int 32) to store[i] which is int.

Use double quotes instead.

```
System.out.print(store[i] + " ");
```

Comment: So the way  to store elements of possibleSeq.get(0) in store is correct ??

Comment: Yes, by calling `possibleSeq.get(0)` you get your array `new Integer[]{1,4,5}`

Comment: I agree with Tala, ASCII code for ' ' char is 32, so the OP program returns 333637 (ie 32+1, 32+4, 32+5).

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.print(store[i] + ' ');
```

As you are printing `(store[i] + ' ')`, `' '` is `char` here which concatenating with the integer value and prints, so it become (1+32) as ascii value of space() is 32. which is 33 and so on...

try this -

```
System.out.print((store[i]) + " ");
```

It works -

```
1 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Use this `System.out.print(store[i] + " ");`

Answer (score 0):

```
  System.out.print(store[i] + ' ');// take a look at this store[0]=1 
                                      and char ' ' is 32
```

Then (1+ 32) you will get.

So change your code

```
System.out.print(store[i] + " ");
```